# False positives against flex:S1172 - Unused function parameters should be removed

Tags: apache-flex, sonarqube

In Flex, event handlers must be defined with an event parameter.
This event parameter is not necessarily used in the event handler.
See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html

That leads to "false positives" against flex:S1172 - Unused function parameters should be removed.

Is there anything you could do about it?

Comment: What is "flex:S1172"?

Comment: If my understanding is correct @david, what you're suggesting is to not raise any issue when the type of the unused parameter is an Event like for instance a MouseEvent ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following JIRA ticket: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARFLEX-52